# Getting name of parent object from value of object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This feels really simple, but I couldn't find a straightforward answer.

I have an object:

```
var obj = {
        'John': {'phone':'7326', 'age': '23'},
        'Paul': {'phone': '9898', 'age': '12'},
        'Lucy': {'phone': '1122', 'age': '24'}
}
```

I have the phone number 9898. How do I get 'Paul' as the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Object.keys() and find()

```js
var obj = {
        'John': {'phone':'7326', 'age': '23'},
        'Paul': {'phone': '9898', 'age': '12'},
        'Lucy': {'phone': '1122', 'age': '24'}
}

const res = Object.keys(obj).find(e => obj[e].phone === '9898');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `find` method on `Object.entries`.

```js
var obj = {'John': {'phone':'7326', 'age': '23'},'Paul': {'phone': '9898', 'age': '12'},'Lucy': {'phone': '1122', 'age': '24'}}
var [name] = Object.entries(obj).find(([_, {phone}]) => phone == 9898) || []
console.log(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do with Object.keys and array find:

```js
var obj = {
        'John': {'phone':'7326', 'age': '23'},
        'Paul': {'phone': '9898', 'age': '12'},
        'Lucy': {'phone': '1122', 'age': '24'}
};
var phone_to_search = '9898';
var result = Object.keys(obj).find(current=>{
  if (obj[current]['phone']===phone_to_search)
    return current;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try either of these:-

```
for(var key in obj){
   if(obj[key].phone == "9898") {
      console.log(key);
   }
}
```

or

```
const key= Object.keys(obj).find(e => obj[e].phone === '9898');
console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
        'John': {'phone':'7326', 'age': '23'},
        'Paul': {'phone': '9898', 'age': '12'},
        'Lucy': {'phone': '1122', 'age': '24'}
}

let givenPhone = '9898'
let userName = 'UNKNOWN';

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([user, {phone}])=> {
  if(phone === givenPhone) userName = user;
})

console.log(userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a function, this way you can reuse the code.
This code goes though the object and compare the phone until it finds a coincidence.

```
var obj = {
    'John': {'phone':'7326', 'age': '23'},
    'Paul': {'phone': '9898', 'age': '12'},
    'Lucy': {'phone': '1122', 'age': '24'}
}

function searchPhone(obj, phone){
  for(var key in obj){
    if(obj[key]['phone'] == phone){
        return key
      }
  }
}

console.log(searchPhone(obj, '9898'))
```